# iTunes Connect In App Purchase free trial duration gone?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

One month ago, I can choose free trial days(3,7days...) for In App Purchase in iTunes Connect, however, I couldn't find it anymore. Do I miss something or does Apple change it silently?

[image]

Comment: It has now moved under "Introductory Pricing"; You now have more flexible options beyond a free trial.

Comment: @Paulw11Thank you for your guide, it is there!

Comment: UPDATE: Sorry, you are correct, it's under introductory pricing, it was just very misleading that you have to specify a start/end date. Please disregard this: (I don't think it's the same. Free trial means that a user can cancel in a given period since his purchase. Introductory pricing means that before  a certain date, we give a discount. Am I mistaken?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please look for it under Introductory Pricing instead, as Paulw11 observes.